# nested arraylist to hashmap in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have below Objects -

Company.java

```
private String compName;
private List<Department> departments;
```

Department.java

```
private String deptId;
private String deptName;
private List<Employee> employees;
```

Employee.java

```
private String empId;
private String legalStatement;
```

I want to return Map of each employee legal statement -

```
Map<String, String> legalStatement = new HashMap<>();
```

For that existing logic is -

```
for(Department department : departments){
   if(department.getEmployees() != null && 
      department.getEmployees().size() > 0){
      for(Employee employee : department.getEmployees()){
        legalStatement.put(employee.getEmpId(), 
        employee.getLegalStatement());
      } 
   }
}
```

How I can write same thing in Java 8 Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream's `filter` for `if`, `flatMap` for internal `employee` list and `collect` to collect as a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> legalStatement = departments.stream()
        .filter(department -> department.getEmployees() != null && !department.getEmployees().isEmpty())
        .flatMap(department -> department.getEmployees().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, Employee::getLegalStatement));
```

Comment: In case there could be `empld`s with multiple occurrences, you can write a `mergeFunction` within the `collect` to decide over what takes the preference.

Answer (score 0):

By using `flatMap` and `ternary` operator

```
Map<String,String> result = departments.stream()
 .flatMap(d->(Objects.nonNull(d.getEmployees()) && !d.getEmployees().isEmpty()) ? d.getEmployees().stream() : Stream.empty())
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, Employee::getLegalStatement));
```

As @nullpointer suggestion if there is a chance for duplicate employee id use `mergeFunction`

```
public static <T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
                                                BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and the results are merged using the provided merging function.